# "Role does not exist" error when granting usage on public schema, but role does exit

Tags: postgresql, schema

In Postgres, I'm trying to grant `USAGE` on the public schema to a specific role -

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO MyRole;
```

The problem is that this command generates an error -

> ERROR:  role "myrole" does not exist

However, the role **does** exist.  Listing roles outputs the following table -

```
   Role name   |                         Attributes                         |    Member of
---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------
 rds_user      | Create role, Create DB                                    +| {rds_superuser}
               | Password valid until infinity                              |
 MyRole        |                                                            | {}
 rds_superuser | Cannot login                                               | {}
 rdsadmin      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS+| {}
               | Password valid until infinity                              |
 rdsrepladmin  | No inheritance, Cannot login, Replication                  | {}
```

I'm new to Postgres, so I may be missing some subtle command, but as far as I can tell I've done everything I need to.  Can anyone suggest what the problem may be and how I should go about resolving it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that the role you are after has capital letters in its name.  Mixing cases is usually a bad idea in PostgreSQL, because you need to [double-quote](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) such names.

So your grant should look like

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO "MyRole";
```

I'd suggest renaming that role to "myrole", to avoid such problems later.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem.  I'll look in to renaming the role at the earliest oppurtunity.